# CakePHP linking css files and javascript files

Tags: cakephp

How do you link css files and javascript/jquery files to a controller/view??

I am using CakePHP_1.3 and have located the following code online, but I cant seem to figure out where to put this, and secondly, where to place the css file named css_file.

```
<?php $this->Html->css("css_file", null, array("inline"=>false)); ?>
```

Any help appreciated guys...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You would put the CSS file in:

```
app/
  webroot/
      css/ <-- here
```

You would put the line of code in your `default.ctp` layout.  This is located in (1.3):

```
cake/
  libs/
      view/
        layouts/
          default.ctp <-- copy this to app/views/layouts/
```

Then open that up `app/views/layouts/default.ctp` and look at the HTML.  You'll see where Cake is already using this command.  Simply replace the filename with the file you added.  Do **not** add the `.css` to the end when you add the line of code.

Comment: thanks Charles, and is it the same way to include javascript/jquery files?

Comment: @DJDonaL300 Sure is, just put the files in `app/webroot/js/` and call `$this->Html->script(...)` wherever you want the `<script src="..."></script>` elements to show up.

Answer (score 8):

you use `echo $this->Html->css('css_file_name_without_the_extension');` and `echo $this->Html->script('same')` in the view

Answer (score 5):

Based on your question, it sounds like you were asking how to do this on a view-by-view basis.

This is where `$scripts_for_layout` comes in useful.

You just need to make sure that it's in your `<head>` tag in `/app/views/layouts/default.ctp` as `<?php echo $scripts_for_layout; ?>`

Then, you can literally add the code you included in your question into any of your views, at literally any point you like. Because you have `'inline' => false` it won't actually appear at that position in the view:

```
<?php $this->Html->css("css_file", null, array("inline"=>false)); ?>
```

...and you'll find that `css_file.css` is automatically linked in your `<head>` whenever that particular view is loaded. This is a great way to only load specific CSS files on a per-view basis when they're needed, yet make sure they appear in the `<head>` tag where they should be.

This also works for JavaScript as follows:

```
<?php $this->Html->script("js_file", null, array("inline"=>false)); ?>
```

If you want to have one or more CSS files loaded in all views, just put a shortened version your code in the `<head>` of `default.ctp` as follows:

```
<?php echo $html->css(array('each','one','of','your','css','files'));
```

Or, again, for JavaScript:

```
<?php echo $html->script(array('each','one','of','your','js','files'));
```

Don't include the .css or .js extension in the array.